# Pandas: select dataframe rows only if the values in a specific column start with

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
    X           Y           A       B
0   484         408         10      3360
1   478         415         24      3365
2   504         452         31      yes
3   613         551         33      maybe
4   663         665         39      no
```

I know how to select the row for which column `B` is `yes` or any other specific value:

```
df1.loc[df1['B'] == 'yes']
```

But how can I select all the rows that **do not start** with `336`?

PS: in my case, `3360` and `3365` are strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something like `df[~df.B.str.startswith('336')]`, using the `str` accessor. For instance,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['3360', '3365', 'yes', 'maybe', 'no']})
>>> df[~df.B.str.startswith('336')]
       B
2    yes
3  maybe
4     no
```

And if you have multiple strings to check, [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) accepts a tuple of prefixes.

```
>>> df[~df.B.str.startswith(('112', '336', 'n'))]
       B
2    yes
3  maybe
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. How would you combine two or more conditions, such as `336` and `545`? Can you use an `or` inside the accessor?

Comment: @CF84 You can supply a tuple to `startswith`. For instance, `df[~df.B.str.startswith(('112', '336', '556'))]`.